# How to populate jtable checkbox values from database?

Tags: java, jtable

I want to add a checkbox to the JTable, when the database value is true or false (currently I am using Oracle database, so its not accepting boolean type).

When the value is true, the checkbox will be shown selected/checked.

Everything is fine, but the JTable displayed like true and false.

Here is my code:

### Function

```
private void loadData(){
  try {
    con = Connection_Config.ConnectDB();
    String sql = "select * from t_module_list";
    ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    rs = ps.executeQuery();

    tab.setModel(buildTableModel(rs));            
  } catch (SQLException ex) {
  }            
}


public static DefaultTableModel buildTableModel(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
  ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();

  // names of columns
  Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<String>();
  int columnCount = metaData.getColumnCount();
  /* for (int column = 1; column <= columnCount; column++) {
  columnNames.add(metaData.getColumnName(column));
  }*/

  columnNames.add("MODULE NAME");
  columnNames.add("SUB_MODULE NAME");
  columnNames.add("ADD");
  columnNames.add("MODIFY");
  columnNames.add("DELETE");
  columnNames.add("VIEW");

  // data of the table
  Vector<Vector<Object>> data = new Vector<Vector<Object>>();

  while (rs.next()) {
    Vector<Object> vector = new Vector<>();
    for (int columnIndex = 1; columnIndex <= columnCount; columnIndex++) {
      System.out.println("rs.getObject(columnIndex)======="+rs.getObject(columnInde  x));     
      if (rs.getObject(columnIndex).equals("false") ||
          rs.getObject(columnIndex).equals("true")) {
        vector.add(new Boolean(true));          
      } else {
        vector.add(rs.getObject(columnIndex));
      }                
    }
    data.add(vector);        
  }

  return new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
}
```

Comment: Please, add your current & expected output with comparison. It's unclear what you're trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your data will need to be objects not strings, something like

```
Object[] data = new Object[columnNames.length];
```

then add your value from the database

```
data[0] = new Boolean(rs.getBoolean(0));
```

then set up your default renderer for the column in question

```
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(
        new MyCellRenderer());
```

and here is the renderer

```
public class MyCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,
                Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row,
                int column) {


            if (value instanceof JComboBox) {
                return (JComboBox) value;
            }
            if (value instanceof Boolean) {
                JCheckBox cb = new JCheckBox();
                cb.setSelected(((Boolean) value).booleanValue());
                return cb;
            }
            if (value instanceof JCheckBox) {
                return (JCheckBox) value;
            }
            return new JTextField(value.toString());
        }

    }
```